# How to copy characters into string vector

Tags: c++11, std, stdvector

Attempting to copy from a character vector to a string vector has been unsuccessful across multiple attempts at a solution

allocating memory to the vector prior to copying allows std::copy to work properly when placed at "OutputIterator result" (based on function template). I attempted:

std::copy(char1.begin(), char1.end(), v1.begin());

however, this was unsuccessful as well. using back_inserter returns error c2679 "binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type'char' (or there is no acceptable conversion).

input file is located here: https://adventofcode.com/2018/day/2

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstdio>



    int main() {

        std::string field1;
        std::string field2;
        char characters;

        std::vector<char>::iterator ptr;
        std::vector<char>::iterator ptr2;

        std::vector<char> char1;
        std::vector<char> char2;

        int size = 0;

        std::ifstream inFile;

        inFile.open("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\c++ files\\input2.txt");

        if (!inFile) {

            std::cout << "abort";

            return 1;

        }

        while (inFile >> characters) {          //read variables from input stream

            char1.push_back(characters);

        }

        std::vector<std::string> v1(6500);

        std::copy(char1.begin(), char1.end(), std::back_inserter(v1)); 

        inFile.close();

        return 0;

    }

    //26
```

expect vector v1 to hold values in vector char1. I am assuming the problem stems from the data type of v1 vs. char1, however, I have not been able to find a concrete solution. I do not want to read directly into a string vector; hence my current problem.

Comment: its not clear what you want the results to be even after looking at the link... a vector of strings where each string has one character? a vector with a single string with all the characters? or a vector of strings where characters are split by some delimiter or other criteria?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you try to achieve. Here few examples:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::string str1{ "Just for an example" }; // You can read it from a file
    std::vector<std::string> vct_str1(32); // Lets say it has 32 std::string items
    std::vector<std::string> vct_str2(32); // Lets say it has 32 std::string items

    // **** A. Copy from std::string to std::vector<char>: ****
    std::vector<char> vct_ch(str1.begin(), str1.end()); // On construction
           // Or later: vct_ch.assign(str1.begin(), str1.end());

    // **** B. Copy from std::vector<char> to std::string: ****
    std::string str2(vct_ch.begin(), vct_ch.end()); // On construction
           // Or later: str2.assign(vct_ch.begin(), vct_ch.end());

    // **** C. Copy from std::vector<char> to std::vector<std::string>: ****
    vct_str1[0].assign(vct_ch.begin(), vct_ch.end()); // Which is similar to B

    // **** D. Source & Dest Types same as in Case-C But char per std::string: ****
    int i = 0;
    vct_str2.resize(vct_ch.size());
    for (auto item : vct_ch)
        vct_str2[i++] = item;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Methods A and B at least can simply be done with the constructors of `vector` and `string`: `std::vector<char>(str.begin(), str.end())` and `std::string(vec.begin(), vec.end())`.